# Interaction Channel messages (Discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
            let messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch();

       messages.then(async (messages) => {
           const output = messages.array().reverse().map(m => `${new Date(m.createdAt).toLocaleString('en-US')} - ${m.author.tag}: ${m.attachments.size > 0 ? m.attachments.first().proxyURL : m.content}`).join('\n');

           console.log(output)
       })
```

and when I get this console log my console log this error:

```
    C:\Users\test7\Desktop\ThunderBot\events\bot\slash-interactionCreate.js:195
           messages.then(async (messages) => {
                    ^
    TypeError: messages.then is not a function
```

interaction.channel data: https://hastebin.com/uwocabepoq.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already `await`ing the messages. This gives the `Collection` of messages which does not have the `.then` method (`.then` exists on `Promise` instances, but not unchanged `Collection` instances). Either remove `await` to get the `Promise` instance or run that without the `.then`

**Removing `await`**

```js
let messages = interaction.channel.messages.fetch();
messages.then(async (messages) => {
    const output = messages.array().reverse().map(m => `${new Date(m.createdAt).toLocaleString('en-US')} - ${m.author.tag}: ${m.attachments.size > 0 ? m.attachments.first().proxyURL : m.content}`).join('\n');
    console.log(output)
})
```

**Removing `.then`**

```js
let messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch();
const output = messages.array().reverse().map(m => `${new Date(m.createdAt).toLocaleString('en-US')} - ${m.author.tag}: ${m.attachments.size > 0 ? m.attachments.first().proxyURL : m.content}`).join('\n');
console.log(output)
```

Comment: In fact, the first solution doesn't need the `async` keyword.

Comment: @qucchia while it doesn't need it, I like to avoid messing around with parts of the code that are fine. That doesn't really affect anything. The same could be said with `messages.then(async (messages)`, this is messy, uses the same variable name twice, but it works and that's not the question